# Add Flink Job Jar in Docker Setup and run Job via Flink Rest API

Tags: apache-flink, flink-batch

We're running Flink in Cluster Session mode and automatically add Jars in the Dockerfile:

```
ADD pipeline-fat.jar /opt/flink/usrlib/pipeline-fat.jar
```

So that we can **run this Jar via the Flink Rest API** without the need to **upload** the Jar in advance:

```
POST http://localhost:8081/:jarid/run
```

But the "static" Jar is now shown, to get the `:jarid`:

```
GET http://localhost:8081/jars
```

---

**So my question is:**

Is it possible to run a `userlib` jar using the `Flink Rest API`?

Or can you only reference such jars via

- CLI `flink run -d -c ${JOB_CLASS_NAME} /job.jar`
- and `standalone-job --job-classname com.job.ClassName` Mode?

---

My alternative approach (workaround) would be to upload the jar in the Docker `entrypoint.sh` of the `jobmanager` container:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8084/jars/upload \
    -H "Expect:" \
    -F "jarfile=@./pipeline-fat.jar"
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it is unfortunately not possible to currently start a flink cluster in session mode with a jar pre-baked in the docker image, and then start the job using the REST API commands (as you showed).

However your workaround approach seems like a good idea to me. I would be curious to see if it worked for you in practice.

Comment: It's currently working, I'll update the thread if we notice issues or find a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to run a userlib jar using the command line interface.

I edited docker compose to run custom docker-entrypoint.sh.
I've add to original docker-entrypoint.sh

```
run_user_jars() {
echo "Starting user jars"
exec ./bin/flink run /opt/flink/usrlib/my-job-0.1.jar & }

run_user_jars
...
```

And edit original entrypoint for jobmanager in docker-compose.yml file

```
entrypoint: ["bash", "/opt/flink/usrlib/custom-docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: I'm happy for you ;-) But in my question above we wanted to "run [a] Job via Flink Rest API" not the CLI. (Although we're currently not using the Flink API anymore, but this question was specifically about that API :) Thanks anyways for your contribution.